# Pyspark create dictionary within groupby

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible in pyspark to create dictionary within `groupBy.agg()`? Here is a toy example:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)

toy_data = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=1, key='a', value="123"),
    Row(id=1, key='b', value="234"),
    Row(id=1, key='c', value="345"),
    Row(id=2, key='a', value="12"),
    Row(id=2, key='x', value="23"),
    Row(id=2, key='y', value="123")])

toy_data.show()

+---+---+-----+
| id|key|value|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  a|  123|
|  1|  b|  234|
|  1|  c|  345|
|  2|  a|   12|
|  2|  x|   23|
|  2|  y|  123|
+---+---+-----+
```

and this is the **expected output**:

```
---+------------------------------------
id |  key_value
---+------------------------------------
1  | {"a": "123", "b": "234", "c": "345"}
2  | {"a": "12", "x": "23", "y": "123"}
---+------------------------------------
```

======================================

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
toy_data.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.create_map(col("key"),col("value")).alias("key_value")
)
```

This yields the following error:

```
AnalysisException: u"expression '`key`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function....
```

Answer (score 11):

The `agg` component has to contain actual aggregation function. One way to approach this is to combine [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list)

> Aggregate function: returns a list of objects with duplicates.

[`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=struct#pyspark.sql.functions.struct):

> Creates a new struct column.

and [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=map_from_entries#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries)

> Collection function: Returns a map created from the given array of entries.

This is how you'd do that:

```py
toy_data.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct("key", "value"))).alias("key_value")
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |key_value                     |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[a -> 123, b -> 234, c -> 345]|
|2  |[a -> 12, x -> 23, y -> 123]  |
+---+------------------------------+
```

Comment: looks like my spark version doesn't have `map_from_entries`. It gives me this error message when running the code above: 
```AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'map_from_entries'```
Is there any other method I could try?

Answer (score 1):

For pyspark < 2.4.0 where `pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries` is not available you can use own created udf function

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType

@F.udf(returnType=MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
def map_array(column):
    return dict(column)

(toy_data.groupBy("id")
     .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("key", "value")).alias("key_value"))
     .withColumn('key_value', map_array('key_value'))
     .show(truncate=False))
```

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |key_value                     |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[a -> 123, b -> 234, c -> 345]|
|2  |[x -> 23, a -> 12, y -> 123]  |
+---+------------------------------+
```