# Group by column and have a column with a value_counts dictionary PYSPARK

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

1

I have a sales table with customer purchase history. I want to make a new dataframe grouped by customer. The dataframe should also include a column with a value_counts dictionary of all the products that customer has purchased and the count of how many of each product

THIS IS WHAT MY DATAFRAME LOOKS LIKE NOW

```
              Description                                     Counts
CustomerID
3004000304    MAJOR APPLIANCES,HOME OFFICE, OTHER STUFF          3
3004000304    HOME OFFICE, MAJOR APPLIANCES                      2
3004000304    ACCESSORIES, OTHER STUFF                           2
3004002756    MAJOR APPLIANCES, ACCESSORIES                      2
3004002946    HOME OFFICE, HOME OFFICE                           2
3004002946    ACCESSORIES, MAJOR APPLIANCES                      2
3004002946    MAJOR APPLIANCES, OTHER STUFF, ACCESSORIES         3
```

I WANT THIS

```
              Counts
CustomerID
3004000304    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'OTHER STUFF':2}
3004002756    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1, 'ACCESSORIES': 1}
3004002946    {'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 2, 'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1,'OTHER STUFF':1}
```

MY APPROACH
I converted the PYSPARK DF to Pandas Df as I don't have much experience with Pyspark and new to it, A direct pyspark help will be much appreciated, else even pandas implementation would be great.

```
f = lambda x: dict(zip(x['Description'], x['Counts']))
df = categories.groupby(level=0).apply(f).to_frame('Counts')
print (df)
```

THIS IS NOT GIVING ME THE EXPECTED RESULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pyspark solution you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308482/pyspark-create-dictionary-within-groupby) SO answer ,

Code will be as

```
df.groupBy("CustomerID").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct("Description", "Counts"))).alias("Description_Counts")
).show(truncate=False)
```

Note that map_from_entries is only available from spark version >= 2.4.0

Edit- As per comment you can use try below code where I first explode each value in column and then group them based on their count

```
dft=spark.createDataFrame([(3004000304,"MAJOR APPLIANCES, HOME OFFICE, OTHER STUFF",3),(3004000304,"HOME OFFICE, MAJOR APPLIANCES",2),(3004000304,"ACCESSORIES, OTHER STUFF",2),(3004002756,"MAJOR APPLIANCES, ACCESSORIES",2),(3004002946,"HOME OFFICE, HOME OFFICE",2),(3004002946,"ACCESSORIES, MAJOR APPLIANCES",2),(3004002946,"MAJOR APPLIANCES, OTHER STUFF, ACCESSORIES",3)],"cid long, descr string, count int")
dft.withColumn("descr",F.explode(F.split("descr",", "))).groupBy("cid","descr").agg(F.count("descr").alias("count")).groupBy("cid").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct("descr", "count"))).alias("Description_Counts")
).show(truncate=False)

# output

+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cid       |Description_Counts                                                           |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|3004002946|{HOME OFFICE -> 2, MAJOR APPLIANCES -> 2, ACCESSORIES -> 2, OTHER STUFF -> 1}|
|3004000304|{OTHER STUFF -> 2, MAJOR APPLIANCES -> 2, HOME OFFICE -> 2, ACCESSORIES -> 1}|
|3004002756|{ACCESSORIES -> 1, MAJOR APPLIANCES -> 1}                                    |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: ``` 3004000304    MAJOR APPLIANCES,HOME OFFICE, OTHER STUFF      -> 3, HOME OFFICE, MAJOR APPLIANCES  ->2
``` this is the output i got

The code is not splitting based on items but each row is assigned a count and not each item.

 I want something like 
3004000304     {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 2, 'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'OTHER STUFF':2}

Comment: Please try code in edit to check if it satisfies your condition

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas version, you may do:

```
from collections import Counter
df['Desc'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x:x.split(","))
df['Desc'] = df['Desc'].apply(lambda x:[e.strip() for e in x])
df2 = df.groupby('CustomerID')['Desc'].agg(sum)
df2['Counts'] = df2['Desc'].apply(lambda x:Counter(x))
```